# Web Service Deployment Issues: Incorrect URL Redirect and EPR Error

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis, webservice-client

As a novice in the field of web services, I am currently in the initial stages of my project development using Eclipse, Axis, and Tomcat. I encountered a challenge when attempting to execute my class, as it led to the opening of the following URL in my web browser: http://localhost:8081/WS_HelloWorld/WEB-INF/classes/tps/ws/deployment/HelloWorld.java, rather than the expected http://localhost:8081/WS_HelloWorld/services/HelloWorld/wsdl. This redirection resulted in a 404 error.

Subsequently, in another project, upon entering the URL, the returned XML presented the following error message:

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /WS_Calculatrice/services/Calculatrice/wsdl, and the WSA Action is null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

I am seeking guidance and assistance in comprehending and resolving these issues.